# Check boxes validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox

I have written this script:

```
function getDays(select){
    var selectedString = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    if(selectedString == 4)
    {
        document.getElementById("days_target").style.display = "block";
    }else {
        document.getElementById("days_target").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

and in `validateForm()` function I have this:

```
var x=document.forms["form1"]["days"].value;
if (x==null || x=="" || x=="Select Days")
{
    alert("Oh, you forgot to select days! :)");
    return false;
}
var x=document.forms["form1"]["days"].value;
if(x=="4")
{
    var cnt = 0;
    for (var i = 7; i < document.day.elements.length; i++) {
        if (document.day.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            if (document.day.elements[i].checked == true) {
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (cnt == 0) {
        alert("Atleast 1 day Should be Selected.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML like this:

```
<b>Please enter days required</b><br/>
<select name="days" id="days" style="width:200px;" onchange="getDays(this)">
    <option value="Select Days" selected>Select Days</option>
    <option value="1">Mon-Fri</option>
    <option value="2">Mon-Fri</option>
    <option value="3">Mon-Fri</option>
    <option value="4">Bespoke Days</option>
</select><br/><br/>
<div id="days_target" style="display:none;">
    <b>Select Days</b><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="mon"/>Mon &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="tue"/>Tue<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="wed"/>Wed &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="thr"/>Thr<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="fri"/>Fri &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="sat"/>Sat<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="sun"/>Sun<br/><br/>
</div>
```

If I select Bespoke days then that check boxes appear and if none is checked then I want to display error message "Atleast one day should be selected." How to do this?

Comment: value can not be null

Answer (score 0):

The *after* function in jquery would allow you to easily do this.  This would require two steps.

1. Load Jquery by putting this inside your header tag in the HTML (`<head></head>`):

   ```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Add javascript in the validation when the condition is not met:

   ```
   $('#days').after('<label class="error">Atleast one day should be selected.</label.');
   ```

Additionally, you will want the error message to go away when the validation rules are met.

1. `$('.error').remove();`

You will probably want to adjust the HTML/CSS for displaying purposes, but that should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Where do you see jQuery mentioned?

Comment: JQuery was not mentioned, but there was also no mention of a native-javascript solution.

Comment: @mplungjan So because the OP didn't specifically mention "JQuery solutions are acceptable", a popular javascript library solution is unacceptable?

Comment: The OP specifically tagged it javascript. The code posted does not have any jQuery. You did not answer the question at all. The script was non functioning and needed to be fixed. Had you fixed the script (and changed the Dom access to jQuery too) then I would not comment, but you just suggested how to show an error message - but not where to add the code, something clearly not obvious to the OP. Confusing the issue with jQuery is not helping the OP at this stage imnsho

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the checkboxes incorrectly. Forms have elements. Also you start from 7 and count up instead of from 0 and count up or from 6 and count down

```
var day = document.forms["form1"].day;
for (var i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
    if (day[i].type == 'checkbox') {
        if (day[i].checked == true) {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
}
```

I would do it like this:

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2CPAn/)**</kbd>

```
var x=document.forms["form1"]["days"].selectedIndex;
if (x<1) {
  alert("Please select days");
  return false;
}
else if(x==4) { // fifth entry 
  var checked = false, chk = document.forms["form1"]["day"];
  for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
    if (chk[i].checked) { checked=true; break }
  }
  if (!checked) {
     alert("At least one day should be checked.");
     return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not working..after checking all checkboxes it gives error message.

Comment: Please try again, I forgot an [i]